# Vanilla JavaScript turn form data into an object with corresponding name and values

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get form data using vanilla JavaScript. Currently what I have now looks like this

```
submit(){
  var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
  let JSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(document.querySelector('form')).entries())));
  console.log(json);
}
```

The output is a JSON which is what i want and looks like this

```
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193a[fee]: "0.966"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193a[max_price]: "400"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193b[fee]: "0.971"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193b[max_price]: "600"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193c[fee]: "0.976"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193c[max_price]: "800"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193d[standard]: "0.981"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193e[fee]: "1.044"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193e[max_price]: "100"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193f[fee]: "1.039"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193f[max_price]: "200"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb1938[fee]: "0.956"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb1938[max_price]: "100"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb1939[fee]: "0.961"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb1939[max_price]: "200"
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb1940[fee]: "1.034"
```

But the problem is that i want the data to look like this

```
5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193a: {
  fee: "0.966",
  max_price: "400"
}
```

Just like in PHP when you send a request and get the fields. Is there any way I can achieve this? I am thinking about finding the begining of `[` and building some custom function but i think that's way too sketchy.

---

Update HTML form

```
             <input
              class="border border-gray-300 duration-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue focus:duration-300"
              name="5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193a[max_price]"
              type="number"
              value="400"
              step="any"
            />
 
            <input
              class="border border-gray-300 duration-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue focus:duration-300"
              name="5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193a[fee]"
              type="number"
              value="0.966"
              step="any"
            />

             <input
              class="border border-gray-300 duration-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue focus:duration-300"
              name="5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193b[max_price]"
              type="number"
              value="400"
              step="any"
            />
 
            <input
              class="border border-gray-300 duration-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue focus:duration-300"
              name="5f5cf7c0123c4224fcfb193b[fee]"
              type="number"
              value="0.971"
              step="any"
            />
```

Comment: So what does the form look like so we do not have to create the HTML

Comment: @epascarello i added a small sample but the data is dynamic and i am using vue to loop through them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built in to do that. A simple reduce loop over the array can map it into the format you are after.

```js
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
var entries = formData.entries();
var data = Object.fromEntries(entries);
var result = Object.entries(data).reduce(function(result, entry) {
  const keys = entry[0].match(/([^[]+)\[([^\]]+)/)
  result[keys[1]] = result[keys[1]] || {};
  result[keys[1]][keys[2]] = entry[1];
  return result
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="a[foo]" value="a-foo-1" />
  <input name="a[bar]" value="a-bar-1" />
  <input name="b[foo]" value="b-foo-1" />
  <input name="b[bar]" value="b-bar-1" />
  <input name="c[foo]" value="c-foo-1" />
  <input name="c[bar]" value="c-bar-1" />
</form>
```